# Create a new DF using another two

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes that shares the column colour, and I would like to create a new column with the Code that correspond to the column colour in a new DF as you can see:

```
DF1
+------------+--------------------+
|    Code    |      colour        |
+------------+--------------------+
|     1001   |      brown         |
|     1201   |      black         |
|     1300   |      green         |
+------------+--------------------+

DF2
+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|    Name    |      colour        |    date   |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|     Joee   |      brown         |  20210101 |
|     Jess   |      black         |  20210101 |
|     James  |      green         |  20210101 |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+

Output:
+------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
|    Name    |      colour        |    date   |   Got    |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
|     Joee   |      black         |  20210101 |  1201    |
|     Jess   |      brown         |  20210101 |  1001    |
|     James  |      blue          |  20210101 |   092    |
+------------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
```

How can I do this? With join?

Comment: just a simple join on the colour column will do. what have you tried?

Comment: df1.join(df2,Seq($"colour"),"inner")

Comment: It is what I am doing but I get all time an empty DF :|

Answer (score 0):

As [mck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14165730/mck) suggested, a simple SQL `join` would be enough for your case, by explicitly specifying the equality of the `colour` column's values between the two DataFrames, as seen below (we drop one of the two `colour` columns since they have the same value for each row after the join):

```
val joined = df1.join(df2, df1("colour").equalTo(df2("colour")))
          .drop(df1("colour"))
```

This is what we get after `show`ing the newly formed `joined` DataFrame:

```
+----+-----+------+--------+
|code| name|colour|    date|
+----+-----+------+--------+
|1001|  Joe| brown|20210101|
|1201| Jess| black|20210101|
|1300|James| green|20210101|
+----+-----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Is not working for me, is there not another way?

Comment: What is the output that you've been given from the console? What is the Spark version you are currently using? Maybe another (more accurate) sample of the data in the two DataFrames could help to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The column "colour" contains a big string which is in both DF but maybe is this a problem? because the column to join is a big string

Comment: Please edit the text of your question with the actual contents of the two dataframes so it can be a bit more clear what exactly needs to be done to solve this.